# finding values not in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have three separate dictionaries

```
d1 = {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4' :4}
d2 = {'5': 5, '7': 7, '9': 9, '10' :10}
d3 = {'12': 12, '23': 23, '30': 30, '14' :14}
```

I want to take a line from a file and test if three columns have values present in those dictionaries. If the values from the three columns are not in the dictionaries, I want to print the line of the file that the non-matches correspond to. Here is what I have written so far:

```
OutputFileName = "results.txt"
OutputFile = open(OutputFileName, 'w')
import csv
with open('inputfile.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        assign1 = row['assign1']
        assign2 = row['assign2']
        assign3 = row['assign3']
        if assign1 in d1:
```

This is where I run into some confusion. I only want assignments that are not in the d1. This is some pseudo-type code for what I would want to do:

```
if assign1 not in d1:
    if assign2 not in d2:
        if assign3 not in d3:
            OutputFile.write(''+assign1+'\t'+assign2+'\t'+assign3+'\n')
```

Is there an easy way to do this with dictionaries? Should I be using `else` statements? I'm having trouble with the implementation of the else's in this case

Comment: So, you want to print the line if _none_ of the `assign`s is in its respective dictionary? Why not just use `if ... and ... and ...:`?

Comment: If this is an accurate representation of your dictionary i.e. `str(x): x` then you should just use a list and convert when necessary

Comment: @SirParselot yes, I think I need to switch to lists. I'm in the process of trying this

Comment: if `assign1` needs to be an int just use `assign1 = int(row['assign1'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are asking. As I understand the question, you want to know how best to add an `else` clause to this complex three-fold `if` statement.

The best way would be not to have three `if` statements, but only one and use `and` to combine the conditions.

```
if assign1 not in d1 and assign2 not in d2 and assign3 not in d3:
    OutputFile.write(''+assign1+'\t'+assign2+'\t'+assign3+'\n')
else:
    # stuff to do when not in all three dicts
```

You could also transform the condition a bit, in case you find this to be more intuitive:

```
if not (assign1 in d1 or assign2 in d2 or assign3 in d3):
```

And you could also get rid of that `not` by swapping the `if` and the `else` case.

Comment: So silly of me. I didn't know I could use `not in` in the case of dictionaries. Thank you :)

Comment: I should probably switch to lists. However, this solved my problem :)